# Каким способом лучше всего отдавать картинку и почему?

Tags: curl, php, безопасность

Есть файл `pic.php`, он получает адреса картинок с разных сайтов вот так:

```
pic.php?url=http://s7.aeroflot.ru/pics/big/012/345.jpg
```

Затем он показывает её. Каким способом лучше всего отдавать картинку, и почему?

Брать картинку курлом (`cURL`) и отдавать вот так:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $pic;
```

Или брать адрес картинки и отдавать вот так:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($url);
```

А, может быть, есть какой-то другой, самый лучший, волшебный способ?

Comment: Лучший способ - отдавать картинку ссылкой. Серьёзно. Я делаю так (задача чуть другая, но смысл тот же): если картинки на диске нет, то она или получается, или генерируется, и перед отдачей складывается на диск в нужное место с нужным именем. И при следующем обращении к странице она будет отдана как статика.

Comment: Даже если при сохранении я сохраню в базу данных связь (URL <=> уникальный id картинки), как потом подменять картинки?

Если картинок 100? Делать 100 запросов или запрос типа IN(...), если MySQL? :)

А из моих вариантов какой лучше? :)

Comment: Если выбирать из двух вариантов - то `cURL` будет жрать больше памяти, значит вариант с `readfile` предпочтительнее. С другой стороны, с помощью `cURL` можно обойти системы защиты от размещения картинок на других ресурсах. Объясните лучше, для чего Вам это нужно - тогда может и появится нормальный совет.

З.Ы. Клёвая жопа.

Comment: readfile тоже не плохо обходит защиты, проверила на фотографии с одноклассники.ру, которые пытаются экономить свои ресурсы. :) А как проверять сколько памяти требует та или иная картинка? :)

Comment: А по Вашему заголовку у вас всегда jpeg. На практике так это врят ли.

Comment: На практике вместо картинки могут ещё вдруг отдать html страницу со зловредными скриптами и редиректами.

@Angelina_Jo уже многим интересно, «Зачем?». С куками одного Васи предоставлять кому угодно возможность смотреть альбомы в ОК?

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, я не знаю как у вас всё устроено, и главное - зачем это надо, поэтому точней сказать не могу. Как вариант: на странице указано

    img src=/images/s7.7ba.ru/ex/dl/0e/7baRu_popa_497978.jpg

И соответствующее RewriteRule, которое при отсутствии такого файла переправит на

    pic.php?url=http://s7.7ba.ru/ex/dl/0e/7baRu_popa_497978.jpg

Ну и, при скачивании - не забыть проверить контент на валидность, записать картинку в файл /images/s7.7ba.ru/ex/dl/0e/7baRu_popa_497978.jpg плюс отдать правильные Content-Type и Content-Length. Например, средствами GD.

Comment: А зачем отдавать правильный Content-Type? Попробовала, если скрипт принимает .png а отдаёт .jpeg, то при сохранении картинки она имеет формат .jpg, хотя ACDSee (например) почему-то всё равно глубокого в душе помнит, что она в прошлой жизни была .png. :)

Comment: >А зачем отдавать правильный Content-Type


Вопрос на 5 баллов!!!

Вы ещё спросите, зачем эти дурацкие RFC соблюдать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так.
делал file_get_contents(url), смотрел, что за тип файла по ссылке, и если это картинка, то отдавал соответствующие заголовки, и само содержимое. В итоге, получилось проксировать. Но возникла проблема - при каждом отображении картинка фактически закачивалсь на сервер, а уже потом отдавалась в браузер. На помощь пришло кэширование. Но при таком способе требуется очень дофига дискового пространства)

Comment: @nolka, дисковое пространство нынче дёшево. Это вообще не тема для обсуждения, 5 баксов в месяц за гигов 20. Если уж у вас такой сервис, что этого требует - не те деньги, чтобы париться. Ну и crontab с удалением давно не юзаемых файлов в руки.

Comment: @klopp, Знаю Я все эти техники, просто проект некоммерческий, ну, т.е., он вообще больше рассматривался как проба пера, и не рассчитывался на получение бабла, поэтому не заморачивался)

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь проксировать картинки. Более эффективно, чем на PHP, можно делать это средством самого веб сервера. Варианты:

1. Apache и директива [ProxyPass модуля mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass);
2. nginx и его [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule);

Вкратце, вы настроите url, например, `/pics/` таким образом, что запросы вида

```
http://site.com/pics/kartinki.site.ru/files/012/345.jpg
```

будут отдавать содержание той картинки. Опционально сохраняя её на диске веб сервера на какое-то время.

Это точно быстрее, мощнее и требует меньше памяти, чем решать ту же задачу скриптом php.

Comment: Спасибо. :) Запомню на лучшее будущее, а пока что у меня Apache. :)

Comment: На Apache тоже можно через [директиву ProxyPass модуля mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). Я пока не пробовал, поэтому без подробностей.